# How to understand "Linearity" in a Linear Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been studying Linear Equations for many years now(actually 7) but didn't get the intuition behind them. Usually it is explained that Linear Equations are called "Linear" because they plot a straight line on Cartesian plane. This doesn't do it for me. I have read posts here and elsewhere, where "Linearity" is explained explained differently in terms of Mapping, Functions etc. but I am still struggling. I am self taught and my Knowledge of Math is at 12th grade(class) level. Any help in this regard would help me move forward in my studies. Thanks much.

Comment: a linear transformation $T$ satisfies $T(\alpha a + \beta b)=\alpha T(a) + \beta T(b)$, with scalars $\alpha,\beta$ and vectors $a,b$

Comment: You can consider a linear equation (or a system of linear equations) as $f(x)=b$ with $x$ unknown, where $f$ is "linear", that is $f(x_1 + ax_2) = f(x_1) + a f(x_2)$.

Comment: They are different kinds of "linear functions". $f(x)=mx+b$ is a linear function in "lower-level algebra" where as a linear mapping/transformation is discussed in the subject of linear algebra. In linear algebra a function like $f(x)=mx+b$ is called *affine* rather than linear. There are also linear functionals.

Comment: The main power of linear equations is that we can solve them exactly. This means if we can make a problem linear, or approximate them well by linear functions then we can solve them too. Approximating functions near a point with linear functions is is a major theme in calculus for this reason.

Comment: If you don't like the word "linear" call them "deg-one" equations, as you call $x^2-5x+6=0$ a "quadratic" equation. "Linear" is a magic word in mathematics that appears in the most various circumstances, many of them far away from a "line" in the plane.